# chrome console accessing dot notation square brackets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dot-notation

Hi I have used dot notation in chrome console multiple times. My first time coming across square brackets in the console. I have no idea how to access that data. Anyone familiar on how to access this dot notation wise. I have tried `open.[[Scopes]]`[image] but of course I get an error..